# Wordpress: How to display a Custom Field in front end

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I created an Custom Field using the plugin ACF. The field is type IMAGE.

I need to show the image in the frontend. I tried with this code, but it only show the POST ID of the image. I need to show the image or at least the image url.

```
    /* PRINT CUSTOM FIELD*/
if(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'MY_CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME', true )!= "" && get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'MY_CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME', true )!= "-"){
        echo  get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'MY_CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME', true ); 
}
```

Comment: `get_field('MY_CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME');` gives you the content of your fields

Comment: So : `$myImage = get_field('MY_CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME');` is enough

Comment: @Stender I get the same as with my code, this number: '7603' which is the post_id of  the image in the media.

Comment: @Stender forget my previous message. It works. thanks.